# How to get checkboxes remained checked after being checked in another device

Tags: php, checkbox

I am facing some issues trying to get checkboxes to stay checked in another device, I am able to get check boxes stay checked within the browser, so after the browser refreshed, the checkboxes remained checked, so is there any idea how i can do this?

so here is my code, firstly i included the dcConnect.php to connect to the database then i retrieve the data from the database to be displayed on a website

```
<?php
include_once("dcConnect.php");

$dcData = "SELECT dcID, dcServerName, dcServerAge, dcServerGender, dcServerMarital FROM dcUsers";

$result = $link->query($dcData);

if($result->num_rows >0){
    echo"<table><tr><th></th><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Age Group</th><th>Gender</th><th>Marital Status</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo"<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='". $row["dcID"] ."' name='". $row["dcID"] ."' value='off' ></input></td><td>". $row["dcID"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerName"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerAge"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerGender"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerMarital"] ."</td></tr>";




    }
    echo "</table>";

    }else{
        echo"no results";

    }

$link->close();



?>
```

Here is my website where the check boxes can stay checked after refreshed but not in another device
http://forstoringdata.com/default.php

Comment: What do you mean by "another device"?

Comment: I see you are using Javascript to keep cookies for them (checkboxes) to stay checked. but you want them to stay also checked in other device? means computer, phone, whatever with diferent UserAgent even another browser within same device? in that case I would store the values in sort of "database session" for each user instead of cookies (only if a user is logged in) unless you want to mess checking the IP instead

Comment: @ David Lavieriyea  may i know how is that done? @ John Hascall yes another device as in another computer or phone like what David Lavieri said

Answer (score 0):

It looks like currently you are using cookies to save the state of the checkboxes. Cookies are stored on the clientside (i.e. the user's computer) and not the server side, which is why you are not seeing the checkbox state preserved across devices.

In order to save and retrieve the checkbox state in the database, you will need to add an additional column to your database table. Following your pattern above, this would probably be a boolean column named something lke 'dcChecked'.

Then when you are printing your inputs, you would want to do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if($row['dcChecked']) { print 'checked' } ?></input>
```

(This is simplified for clarity, you'll still want to include your other attributes for ID, name, etc)

Comment: hi, appreciate the reply, i have some issues inputting this code that you suggest to me inside the while statement, i was wondering if you can show me the correct syntax, i hope i am not asking too much, really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include_once("dcConnect.php");

$dcData = "SELECT dcID, dcServerName, dcServerAge, dcServerGender, dcServerMarital, dcChecked FROM dcUsers";

$result = $link->query($dcData);
?>

<?php if($result->num_rows > 0): ?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th><th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age Group</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Marital Status</th>
  </tr>
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id="<?php print $row["dcID"]; ?> " name="<?php print $row["dcID"]?>" value='off' <?php if($row["dcChecked"]): ?>checked<?php endif;?>></input></td>
    <td><?php print $row["dcID"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php print $row["dcServerName"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php print $row["dcServerAge"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php print $row["dcServerGender"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php print $row["dcServerMarital"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php else: ?>
  No results
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's what the syntax would look like in context. I also refactored this a bit to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I really appreciate your reply, i have changed to this syntax. I just want to confirm if this code means that someone will have to change the boolean values in the database for the check boxes to remain checked. Actually I wanted the checkbox to remain checked when someone check it, not through editing the database, so i was thinking of submitting a form, so if the checkboxes were checked it will change the boolean values to true and if the boolean is true the checkboxes will remain checked, I am wondering if this is possible. Thank you for the reply once again :)

Comment: Hi Nigel, Yes, for this code to work, you will need to update the value in the database. If you have not done so already, you will need to create a submit handler that will capture the form values and use them to update the value in the database. A complete explanation of how to do this is beyond what I can provide in a comment, but there are lots of tutorials you can find online. 
Here is a video tutorial I founded that should get you pointed in the right direction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wp6Ngpk5XiY

Comment: And just to clarify - you will not need someone to manually edit the database directly. This will be done using PHP code that is called when the form is submitted. The video tutorial linked above should explain all of this.

Comment: Hi Nathan, sorry for the very late reply, I have seened the video suggested unfortunately, it is not quite what I am looking for. I am not trying to insert data to the database, I am trying to update the values of the boolean to 1 when Specific checkboxes are checked and vice versa after submitting the form, but i did learn something from the tutorial :)